# how can I make a 2D softmax Layer?

Tags: keras, softmax

I am making a network using keras library.

Lets suppose that I have 2D matrix

[ 0 0 1 2

0 1 2 5

1 0 0 1 ]

what I want to do is obtaining the following matrix

[ 0.00 0.00 0.02 0.10

0.00 0.02 0.10 **0.99**

0.02 0.00 0.00 0.02 ]

As shown I want to make the layer to express the largest element of 2d array to be emphasized only.

How can I achieve this?

Is this can be simply achieved by simply adjusting softmax twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take the softmax over the entire 2D array. If so, applying directly the softmax to a 2D array will return the softmax over each column (separately!). E.g.:

```
X = np.log([[1, 1, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
Y = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(X)
assert np.allclose(Y, [[0.25, 0.25, 0.5], [0.3333, 0.3333, 0.3333]], atol=1e-4)
```

If you want the softmax over all elements of the 2D vector, this should do:

```
X = np.log([[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 4]])
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)  # add batch dim

X = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,))(X)  # the batch dimension will be preserved (shape in Reshape doesn't include the batch dim)
# equivalent to: X = X.reshape(m, -1), where m is the batch dim.
# This however will not keep track of the gradients for backprop. 
#That's why, it's better to use a Reshape layer.
Y = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(X)
assert np.allclose(Y, [[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about the 2d shape, the softmax will work fine.

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal(shape=(3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.activations.softmax(inputs)
print(inputs)
print(outputs)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[-0.3471133  -0.8292573  -0.06646241]
 [-1.2869339  -0.52089226  0.3157407 ]
 [-0.8821394   0.16500719 -0.41590676]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.33996844 0.2099163  0.4501153 ]
 [0.12319015 0.26501083 0.61179894]
 [0.18370579 0.52347124 0.29282293]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it applied well to 3d shape? I mean, I want to softmax 10 2D array for an array that has shape of w x h x 10